# Creating plugin with FireBreath and Libsdl

Tags: sdl, firebreath

I am trying to develop a plugin with Firebreath. I could refer the sample and create a test plugin. Now I decided to create the UI part with the LIBSDL.

When I created a window using SDL, it creates a new window, ie, a window outside browser.

Is it possible to create window within the plugin area using LIBSDL?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SDL, so I don't know, but what you'd need to do is have SDL create a window that was a child window of the plugin's HWND.  Alternately, see if you can find a way to create a window and then pass it to SDL to use

Comment: Thanks Taxilian. If I use, SDL window as child window of the Plugin's HWND, can i use it in all platforms like Mac and unix?

Comment: Could you please suggest me a library for creating UI in firebreath plugin that can be supporrted in all platforms?

Comment: HWND is windows only.  I don't know of any UI abstraction that just works cross platform.

Comment: Is there any way to create UI in FireBreath that supports cross platform?

Comment: With FireBreath you can have code that is specific to one platform; there are several good design patterns for this.  Most of us just do the UI in HTML so that we don't have to rely on platform drawing.  Some use OpenGL (tricky, and somewhat limited).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in sdl 1.2.15 you can set an environment variable named SDL_WINDOWID whose value is then used in sdl.
Assuming you are using windows, in your firebreath plugin you can do:

```
bool YourPlugin::onWindowAttached(FB::AttachedEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *win)
{
    // The window is attached; act appropriately
    FB::PluginWindowWin *wnd = dynamic_cast<FB::PluginWindowWin*>(win);
    set_sdl_window (wnd->getHWND());
    // then run your code
    // ...
}
```

and somewhere in your SDL client code is defined the following:

```
int set_sdl_window(HWND window)
{
    char windowid[20] = {0};
    char env[100] = {0};
    if (window != NULL) {
        SDL_ulltoa((Uint64)window, windowid, 10);
        sprintf(env, "SDL_WINDOWID=%s", windowid);
        SDL_putenv (env);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```